# The no. of processes is exponential even when i am not using parent process

Tags: c, fork

Even when i run the part of the code which outputs something only in the child process but the output is coming many times. like here i gave chunks=8 but the output is like 100+ times.

```
Here is the code:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(){

int chunks=8;

int proc[25];
for(int proc_iter=0;proc_iter<chunks;proc_iter++){
    proc[proc_iter]=fork();

    if(proc[proc_iter]==0){
    printf("I am getting called with i=%d",proc_iter);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is because forking will occur in child processes, too.

Comment: Try `chunks=2` or `chunks=3` and use `getpid` and `getppid` to print the pid and parent's pid of each process.

Comment: the posted code seems to be ignoring the fact that the `fork()` function has three(3) kinds of returned values  1) <0, means an error occurred 2) ==0 means executing a child process 3) >0 means executing a parent process.  Every child process should return, not continue in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This issue here is that the child process is performing the same loop as the parent process, so it forks as well.

If you set `chunks` to 2 and add the following loop after the initial loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<chunks;i++){
    printf("pid %d, i=%d, proc[i]=%d\n",getpid(),i,proc[i]);
}
```

You'll get output that looks something like this:

```
I am getting called with i=0
pid 30955, i=0, proc[i]=30956
pid 30955, i=1, proc[i]=30958
pid 30957, i=0, proc[i]=0
pid 30957, i=1, proc[i]=0
pid 30956, i=0, proc[i]=0
pid 30956, i=1, proc[i]=30957
I am getting called with i=1
pid 30958, i=0, proc[i]=30956
pid 30958, i=1, proc[i]=0
```

On the first iteration of the loop, one new process is created.  Then both processes separately iterate the loop a second time and each forks another child.  All four processes then complete the loop.

If you don't want the child processes to loop as well, have the child call `exit`:

```
if (proc[proc_iter]==0) {
    printf("I am getting called with i=%d\n",proc_iter);
    exit(0);
}
```

Then the output will look something like this:

```
I am getting called with i=0
I am getting called with i=1
pid 31020, i=0, proc[i]=31021
pid 31020, i=1, proc[i]=31022
```